# How to trigger events in dynamically changed element in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I need to trigger mousedown event in dynamically changed element. I am making a image galary where if I click on small image then large image should be displayed with high quality image and user can view image by dragging large image in small div. For this is just changing the src of large image container image from jquery. Below is my code:

```
 $(document).on("click", "#thumb_img", function () {
        $("#loading").show();
        var smallimg = $(this).attr("src");
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = smallimg.replace('thumbnail/', 'images/');
        img.onload = function () {
            $(".large-img").prop("src", this.src);
            $("#loading").hide();
        };
        $("img.large-img").css({
            width: "500px",
            height: "100%",
            position: "unset"
        });
    });
```

Above code changes the src of large image when small image is clicked and below code is for enabling drag on the large image generated.

```
   var selected = null, // Object of the element to be moved
        x_pos = 0, y_pos = 0, // Stores x & y coordinates of the mouse pointer
        x_elem = 0, y_elem = 0; // Stores top, left values (edge) of the element

 // Will be called when user starts dragging an element
function _drag_init(elem) {
    // Store the object of the element which needs to be moved
    selected = elem;
    x_elem = x_pos - selected.offsetLeft;
    y_elem = y_pos - selected.offsetTop;
}

 // Will be called when user dragging an element
 function _move_elem(e) {
 //    alert("ASdf");
    x_pos = document.all ? window.event.clientX : e.pageX;
    y_pos = document.all ? window.event.clientY : e.pageY;
    if (selected !== null) {
        selected.style.left = (x_pos - x_elem) + 'px';
        selected.style.top = (y_pos - y_elem) + 'px';
    }
}

 // Destroy the object when we are done
function _destroy() {
    selected = null;
}
 // Bind the functions...
 document.getElementById('large-img').onmousedown = function () {
    _drag_init(this);
    return false;
 };


 document.onmousemove = _move_elem;
 document.onmouseup = _destroy;
```

This code works fine when page loads first time. Then When I clicked in another small image and It doesn't works.

*EDITED*

I had mentioned my code in [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3abLhrep/2/). You can see the image is draggable when page loads in large image container but when you click on other thumbnail and try to drag the image in large image container then drag event is not triggering.

Comment: can you provide a sample of your code on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I had mentioned in jsfiddle. Have a look please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`position: "unset"` is the problem. Removed it and the problem gone.

http://jsfiddle.net/3abLhrep/3/

Answer (score 1):

From your description and code, it looks like you have more than one element with id `thumb_img`, but IDs must be unique.

Comment: yes. It was my mistake. I corrected it. But it was not the problem for the solution.